# Typescript and NodeJS : ReferenceError : Module is not defined

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am making a NodeJs console application with NodeJS Tools for Visual Studio (http://nodejstools.codeplex.com/) with the Typescript template.

Here is basicaly my code :

app.ts :

```
/// <reference path="Module/Module.ts" />
var foo = new Module.ModuleClass();
foo.foo();
```

Module/Module.ts :

```
module Module {
    export class ModuleClass {
       foo() {
        console.log('Hello World');
       }
   }
}
```

The compiler run without trouble but on runtime, NodeJS can't find the module. Here is the error :

```
var foo = new Module.ModuleClass();
              ^
ReferenceError : Module is not defined
```

I tired a lot of thing about that problem (using or not the ///  but I can't find any solution.

Excuse me for my English, I am not a native speaker.
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export `Module` in Module/Module.ts

```
export module Module { ...
```

In app.ts, you need to `require('./Module/Module')`

```
import M = require('./Module/Module');
var foo = new M.Module.ModuleClass();
foo.foo();
```

You need to do this because this node.js uses the commonjs module system, which typescript supports via its "external" modules feature and a compiler arg `--module commonjs`

Comment: I thought I tested that, but it seemed I didn't -_-. It works for this simple case, the problem is we don't have only one module. We have some sub module (Module.SubModule1, Module.SubModuel2) and certain Modules are also written into several files. How can we achieve that simply ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to mix internal and external modules. TypeScript does not support this scenario directly, but you could use a bundling tool like webpack to convert your internal module into a commonjs-compatible module.

Comment: All we wanted to do was to split our code and classes into several files. We just add a lot of import in each file :D. Thanks for Webpack, we will use it next time ;-).